# Creating Table in R Using List of Values from Another Dataset with Different Length

Tags: r, syntax, variable-length, frequency-table

I have a dataset of 50,000+ observations and I'm trying to create a table of my two variables of interest, `chemical` and `lab_code`. The code below outputs a working table that can be used to create a basic heatmap, but like the the main dataset, it only contains 10 lab codes.

```
table(lab_data$chemical, lab_data$lab_code)
```

I have a txt file simply listing all 30 lab codes, but I'm struggling to create a table that take arguments of different lengths and will have many columns of zeros. The length of lab_data$chemical is 50,000+ and the length of codes$lab_code is 30.

```
table(lab_data$chemical, codes$lab_code)
```

> Error in table(lab_data$chemical, codes$lab_code) : all arguments must have the same length

Comment: Is the `lab_data$chemical` vector composed of unique values ?

Comment: Try `merge(lab_data, codes)`, just a guess

Comment: No, lab_data$chemical consists of 20 unique chemicals

Comment: Can you copy and paste the output of both `dput(lab_data[sample(1:nrow(lab_data), 100, replace=FALSE), ])` and `dput(codes$lab_code)`

Comment: Or contact me on Telegram `@julauto` (or any media found on my Stack Overflowv page)

Comment: Try `merge(lab_data, codes, all.x = T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
table(lab_data$chemical, factor(lab_data$lab_code, levels(as.factor(codes$lab_code))))
```